# JS failing to create a date object

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare between two strings representing dates.

```
var val1 = "02-12-2015";
var val2 = "27-11-2015";

var date1 = new Date(val1);
var date2 = new Date(val2);
```

In date1 I get the date object but in date2 I get "Invalid Date".
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: This is because JS is reading your date in "mm-dd-yyyy". Always try "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: @Rajesh—no, don't do that. Manually parse strings or use a library, do not trust Date to parse strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Date()` can parse multiple date formats, but `DD-MM-YYYY` is not one of them. The closest matching format to your string is `MM-DD-YYYY`, so it tries to use the day as month and vice versa. This works with your first example by chance, but not with the second.

You can convert your date like this:

```
var pattern = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
var date2  = new Date(val2.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));
```

The format `YYYY-MM-DD` makes sure there are no misinterpretations.

More valid formats are described in the [`Date.parse()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: or just `var date1 = new Date(val1.split("-").reverse().join("-"))`

Comment: Thank you. it is a valid format in php, didn't think it would be different in js.  Are the timestamps also different? or is it universal?

Comment: Do not parse strings using the Date constructor or Date.parse (essentially the same thing), always manually parse strings. Either use a library or write a function. The silly part is a function to do it properly is the same amount of code as yours (see [*Parse Date String to Date in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076865/parse-date-string-to-date-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the Date constructor to parse strings as it is extremely unreliable. Always manually parse strings, either using your own function or a library. To parse the format in the OP and validate the values, you can use a simple function like:

```js
function parseDMY(s) {

  // Get the number parts
  var b = s.split(/\D/);

  // Create a date
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);

  // Check that it's a valid date. If not, return a Date with time value
  // set to NaN (per ES5 and ECMAScript 2015 standards)
  return b[1] == d.getMonth()? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseDMY('02-12-2015'))
```

Answer (score -2):

When one string argument is passed, it is a string representation of a date, in the format accepted by the Date.parse() method.
Date(dateString) constructor accept both RFC822 and ISO 8601 formatted date strings.

Examples of RFC822-formatted date strings include "Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 EDT +0000", "'25 December, 2010 6:00:00 Am'" and "15 Aug 2005". Note that supplying a two digit year as in "Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01" won't work in JavaScript!
The international ISO (ISO 8601) spec defines a format of "YYYY-MM-DD" which eliminates the ambiguities caused by the dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy formats. For example, using the international format, "3rd of April 2002" would be expressed as "2002-04-03".

Date constructors nor the Date.parse() function throw errors. Instead they result in a NaN value.
We can use that to test a date's validity. 
Below function that can be applied to any string to determine whether or not it represents an acceptable date format:

```
String.prototype.isValidDate = function isValidDate() {
    return !isNaN(Date.parse(this));
}
```

So it seems date your new Date() with string parameter are not valid as per both RFC822 and ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Its humble request to all those who are voting down to it please let me know whats wrong in this.I am here to learn so please correct me if i am wrong at any point...Thanks a lot

Comment: Not my down vote, but prior to ES5, there was **no** specified format for date strings. Since then, there is only one format specified by ECMA-262, all others are implementation dependent.