# how to parse a date in format "DD-MON-YY hh.mm.ss.fff am" that received from database

Tags: javascript

How to parse the following string value to date in javascript?

This is the string value "25-FEB-17 04.00.02.540 AM"

```
Date.parse("25-FEB-17 04.00.02.540 AM", 'DD-MON-YY hh.mm.ss.fff AM');
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date String to Date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076865/parse-date-string-to-date-in-javascript)

Comment: [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Syntax) only accepts one argument, not two. I suggest you use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the dots with colons, which can be done with the regex `/\./g` using the **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method:

```js
var input = '25-FEB-17 04.00.02.540 AM';
input = input.replace(/\./g, ':');

var d = new Date(input);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Isn't using the single-argument `Date` constructor frowned upon for formats other than ISO 8601? Browser implementations are wildly variant

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of the `Date` constructor being frowned upon for different formats. Personally if I need a different format I just output in the desired format. With a single argument it's based off of UTC, yes, but I usually supplement this with `new Date(Date.UTC())` or `.setUTCHours()` if I need a local time.

Comment: I meant a single string argument. See the note here under the `dateString` title ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Date.parse recognizes only certain inputs.

[ECMAScript 6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) Date Time String Format upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format.

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

Check out the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```
Date.parse(dateString)
```

> dateString is a string representing an RFC2822 or (a variant of) ISO 8601 date.
>
> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended
>   to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent,
>   especially across different ECMAScript

The ECMAScript specification states:

> If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may
>   fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or
>   implementation–specific parsing algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or
>   dates containing illegal element values in ISO formatted strings shall
>   cause Date.parse() to return NaN.

Comment: This is all very good information but doesn't really provide an answer

Comment: I think the only way is to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string and then pass it to the constructor separately in the [format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). 


`new Date(year, month [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`